# MAX-FILES param in WRITE HDFS component issue

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, ab-initio

I have a hadoop table which is partitioned on event_date and MAX_FILES param is set as 200. Now I am trying to load 180 days data. Technically it should work as it will open 180 files. But it's failing. If I assign a higher value e.g. 300, it is working. What could be the reason?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: When you say "MAX-FILES", are you refering to the `hive.exec.max.created.files` property?

Comment: If you create the table (with a sufficiently high setting) and then count your files, do you find a number between 200 and 300?

Comment: @JaimeCr .. there is a parameter MAX_FILES in Write HDFS component. I have set this as 200.

Comment: @Dennis Jaheruddin.. I am actually getting a much higher file count -  hdfs dfs -ls /b2b/cs/base/rs_groups_b|wc -l
1075
still, 300 as MAX_FILE parameter is working fine. How is this possible?

Comment: Are you sure you are counting the location of the table? I would expect it to be somewhere in /apps/hive/warehouse

Comment: yes. this is the table location.